# Python socket client doesn't exit

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to develop my simple server/client scripts to send some useful information about systems  using platform module and saved in .txt file on the server side ( in order o improve my programming skills ) but when I run the client side it doesn't send any information till I closed  using  Ctrl+c  but what I really want is the client to send informations then it close itself I tried the sys.exit but it doesn't work

this is the server Side

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import  sys
host = ' '
port = 1060
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('',port)) #bind server
s.listen(2)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print addr , "Now Connected" 
response =  conn.recv(1024)
print response
saved = open('saved_data.txt','w+')
saved.write(response) # store the received information in txt file

conn.close()
```

and this is the client side

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import platform
import  sys


def socket_co():
   port = 1060
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.connect(('192.168.1.107', port)) # my computer address and the port
   system = platform.system()
   node = platform.node()
   version = platform.version()
   machine = platform.machine()
   f = s.makefile("r+") #making file to store information ( as I think it do ) using the makefile()
   f.write('system: ' + str(system) + '\n')
   f.write('node: ' + str(node) + '\n')
   f.write('version: ' + str(version) + '\n')
   f.write('machine: ' + str(machine) + '\n')
   sete = f.readlines() #read lines from the file
   s.send(str(sete))
   while True:
       print "Sending..."
   s.close()
   sys.exit() #end the operation


   def main():
       socket_co()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

Comment: You have a While True which will loop for ever, you will never get to the close or sys.exit() which is not necessary. Does the send method not block till it is done sending?

Comment: even if I remove the while loop the client  doesn't send any informations to the server  till I stop it with Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is cached in memory before sending. You have to `flush` after writing:

```
   f = s.makefile("r+") #making file to store information ( as I think it do ) using the makefile()
   f.write('system: %s\n' % system)
   f.write('node: %s\n' % node)
   f.write('version: %s\n' % version)
   f.write('machine: %s\n' % machine)
   f.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
       print "Sending..."
```

loops forever. So the problem is not in the send part.

Comment: even if I remove the while loop the client doesn't send any informations to the server till I stop it with Ctrl+C